# replace a line with bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to replace a line of my file. I used

```
line=" abc"
sed -i "3c ${line}" test.txt
```

It works but the first space doesn't show up. I want the line 3 in test.txt to be

```
 abc
```

rather than

```
abc
```

notice there is a space before `abc`. thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

```
line="\ abc"
sed -i "3c\
$line" test.txt
```

Escaping the space will keep it from being trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a sed replacement command is `'s/match/replacement/'`. In order to find abc and replace it, you need to do something like:

```
line=" abc"
sed -i "s/^abc$/$line/" test.txt
```

The characters `^` and `$` are regular expression meta characters for the beginning and the end of the line, respectively. So `^abc$` will only match lines containing exactly that pattern and then replace it with `abc` with the space before it.

Comment: `abc` is what he's adding, not something being matched for replacement.